# How to communicate between different winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a container `WinForm` called `frmMain` which holds another forms like `frmOrder`, `frmMessage`, the subforms was added in a `TabPage` control.

What I want to do is communicating between subforms, say user changes something in `frmOrder` and `frmMessage` need to be notified, currently I think the communication need to be delegated through the `frmMain`.

One solution I can think is to make subforms deriving from my custom `Form` derived class which defines interface say:

```
public class MessageEnabledForm: Form 
{
    public void SendMessage(String destFormName, String messageType, String data);
    public void ReceiveMessage(String destFormName, String messageType, String data);
}
```

I don't know whether this is feasible, and is there any other solutions I can employ? which is generic and needn't to know the concrete subform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an **Interface** like this, that all the child forms implement:

```
public interface Communication
{
    public delegate void SendMessageDelegate(String destFormName, String messageType, String data);
    public event SendMessageDelegate SendMessage;

    public void ReceiveMessage(String destFormName, String messageType, String data);
}
```

When the main form receives the event, it can iterate over its "child" forms looking for a match on `destFormName` then call its ReceiveMessage() implementation (after casting it to the Communication interface).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, I don't think inheritance is the best tool for the job.  I say its not the best choice because you are not dealing with an "is a" relationship.  I think you should consider using Events and Delegates to handle the communication between forms and subforms.     The following MSDN article provides a good overview of [Handling and Raising Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You also may want to refresh yourself on the .NET [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29) if you using data binding in the subforms.